# Meteor and Unity3D

Tags: meteor, unity-game-engine

Does anyone tried this before?
I am trying for a while and I have managed to get the "Invalid data file error" when loading the project into meteor page.
It is pretty far for a noob, but not working yet so I've tried the most famous solutions to correct it:
 - I've renamed the "**UnityProject.unity3d**" file to **.zip** and **.jpg** extension and in the js reference as well
*(this is a common hack to trick the MEME issue for some servers)*
 - I've translated the **UnityObject2.JS** to be read by Meteor environment with no error
 - I've removed the DOCTYPE two code lines from the **UnityProject.HTML** file, so Meteor can stop complaining about it :)

Nothing worked so far ... unfortunately.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok guys, good news.
I've got it and I am going to describe some kind of "Hello world!" between Meteor and Unity3D.
- Create Meteor Project
- Erase all files Meteor creates for you.
- Upload both **"Unity Project Web Player Built"** files to your project:

1- The .HTML file
- You have to delete the "DOCTYPE" and "html" lines in the beginning of this file

2- The .unity3d file
- You may need to rename it to JPG extension so most of the servers can load it
- If you did that, you will need to change the reference inside the .html file, like this:
u.initPlugin(jQuery("#unityPlayer")[0], "**/WebPlayer.jpg**");
Notice the **'/'**, this is something you need, because this file (unity3d renamed to jpg) will be in your public folder, so meteor can find it.

That is it, no translation, no nothing, just a few adjustments.
Hope it helps someone.


P.S.: By **"Unity Project Web Player Built"** I mean the two files Unity3D creates when you build some Unity3D project to Web Player.

Answer (score 2):

Wow - sorry it's taken me so long - and sorry for the bump. I'm the person who gave the original talk and I totally did not see this question! I'm sure it's long outdated, but for the record, yes, we published our code here:

http://ump.voidalpha.com

(UMP = Unity Meteor Pong)

If you scroll down to the bottom, there should be a couple of links to the C# and JS code that helps build the bridge between the two.

Hope that helps!

Aaron

Comment: Great talks and thanks for posting the UMP content and code. You've mentioned before that you never implemented a "Direct to Meteor" DDP bridge for Unity and that you have to go from Unity -> Meteor Client -> Meteor Server. Have you had any progress on that?  Is that what this project does? https://github.com/hiddenswitch/Meteor-Unity

Comment: You're welcome! :)

We haven't implemented the DDP bridge, but the project you linked to looks like a very good start. I don't know how exactly that project works, but it looks like it goes directly from inside Unity to the Meteor server (note the "Meteor.Method" line), bypassing the Meteor client. The nice thing about that is that it lets you do native as well.

We found that the hard part is not building the DDP client - there's a clear spec for that. It's in all the subtleties of doing data management, recreating minimongo, etc. to be a 'real' Meteor Client.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand anything in Unity3D but some other people do. And they came to one of Meteor Devshop and have given this talk about their Meteor app and a Unity game: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7HCUNJUvAek

Comment: Yeah, I saw this and it is awesome, but no codes or tips on how to connect one thing to another.
If you see something like that please give me a heads up, I am having trouble in the very first part... getting something to appear from Unity3D in a Meteor app. I've got both but they don't want to work together for some reason.

Thanks.

Comment: @JeanCarlosRacoski I watched the talk long time ago, but don't they say they have a C#->JS bridge that they open-sourced somewhere? Watch it again :)

Comment: Ok **imslavko**, like I said in the first place, I am using some guy named "UnityObject2.JS" and it was to work, just like **Bjorn** posted as well. However, I've downloaded this JS from 4Shared and had to change a few things that Meteor was complaining, and even then, no sucess. I wonder if there's somebody who made a tutorial, kinda "hello world" Meteor & Unity3d :)
Thanks guys for all the attention.

Comment: **Bjorn**, this link is where I've started, it is good but it does not cover all the coding blanks. But you are right, that is indeed the way to start studying this topic. Thanks for the help.

Comment: As I said, I have no knowledge about Unity. But quick googling found this, did you try it? https://github.com/hiddenswitch/Meteor-Unity